# Firebug can't individuate css selector

Tags: php, html, css, firebug

I'm trying to catch a css selector by firebug of a part in html page but seems doesn't exist and firebug can't see it. It can't see the dotted line between the item menu on top. This is the website: http://debatoversigt.dk/index.php/ct-menu-item-3.
Maybe this dotted line is made by a php script?

I don't know the reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dotted line is a background image that is set on the `ul.art-hmenu>li:before` pseudo-element.

Here's the CSS you want to look at / remove:

```
ul.art-hmenu>li:before {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  content: ' ';
  top: 0;
  left: -1px;
  width: 1px;
  height: 43px;
  background: url('../images/menuseparator.png') center center no-repeat;
}
```